# Doctrine ODM - Specify collection name for MappedSuperclass

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-odm, mappedsuperclass

Doctrine ODM has annotation (collection) to specify which name should be used for collection. It defaults to class name but can be changed easily.

However I have mapped superclass which is extended by other classes. Inheritance type is single collection and this collection is named after the base abstract class. How can I change this name?

Let's say I have class Base, that gets extended. But I want the collection to be named Items. I obviously don't want to change annotations in all extending classes as it is quite redundant and prone to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)

> A mapped superclass cannot be a document and is not queryable.

thus it can't be mapped to any collection. You need to have a class having `@Document` and `@InheritanceType` annotations specified from which further documents will extend (the class can be `abstract`). You can either put it in between your mapped superclass or just have it instead. Also thanks to having a `@Document` mapped class you'll be able to query it while having concrete classes back.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the point of MappedSuperclass. I somehow always thought it is alias for abstract and every class that is abstract should be MappedSuperclass. Changing the mapped superclass to document (and keeping it abstract) solved my problem.